# crontab executing hour apart , both set to BST: 2 servers. Why?

Tags: date, time, server, cron

I've just moved servers and have overlap on crontabs running.
Both servers set to BST, but one sends me a log at
08:00 BST the other old one 09:00 BST

The crontab entry for both is

```
0 9 * * * /root/phpmaillog.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Mystery?

Comment: try restarting crond.

Comment: Are you sure that cron has been started with the correct TZ environment variable

Comment: You star, I must have changed the date to BST on the new server and never rebooted!! But of course on a Linux box, why would that cross my mind. MANY THANKS

Comment: "restarting crond. SUCCESS" - THANK YOU